# What's the equivalent in python for javascript's every()?

Tags: javascript, python

I have this code i'm translating from js to python and i have this:

```
if( this.risultato.every((v, i) => v === this.atteso[i]) ){}
```

whats the equivalent in python for the `every();` function and if it's not builtin how do i create a similar function? For the arrow function part i came onto this solution:

```
lambda v, i: v == self.atteso[i]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the equivalent  in python is `all` function:

```
mylist = [True, True, True]
x = all(mylist)
```

Or:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if all(self.risultato[i] == self.atteso[i] for i in len(self.risultato)):
```

seems like a direct translation.  Or,

```
if all( i==j for (i,j) in zip(self.risultato, self.atteso)):
```